# Copy constructor for a doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I am having problems making a copy constructor.
Consider the code below:

In List.h

```
template <class T>
struct ListNode
{
    T value;
    ListNode<T> *next;
    ListNode<T> *prev;

    ListNode(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};

template <class T>
class List
{
    ListNode<T> *head;

public:
    List();
    List(const List<T>& otherList); // Copy Constructor.
    ~List();
    };
```

In list.cpp

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
    head=NULL;
}
template <class T>
List<T>::~List()
{
}
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
}
```

//    I have google the problem. Concept is simple. Make a new head and assign its node the //values of old List node.
//    So for I have tried the following.

```
ListNode<T> *old = head; // pointer to old list.
ListNode<T> *new;// pointer to new head.

while (old->next!=NULL){
new->value = old->value;
old = old->next; 
}
```

// The only problem is how to make a new head that would point to my new Copied list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole question is unclear, and there are a number of problems with the code, including a useless destructor, and not copy assignment operator.

You can't generally define templates in a `.cpp` file, the entire template definition must be visible to all users of the code, which generally means defining the entire template in header files.

```
ListNode<T> *new;// pointer to new head.
```

`new` is a keyword in C++, you can't use it for variable names.

> // The only problem is how to make a new head that would point to my new Copied list.

What copied list? You haven't actually copied anything or created any new nodes.

You need to create copies of the nodes in `otherList`

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
  ListNode<T>* node = otherList.head;
  ListNode<T>** tail = &head;
  while (node)
  {
    *tail = new ListNode<T>(node->value);
    tail = &tail->next;
    node = node->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: All I am saying is that to make a new List (that would contain the elements of the old List) you need to define a head to the newList. how would you do that. ListNode<T> *head = new ListItem<T> or what?????

Comment: No, that would declare a local variable, but you want to assign it to the member `head`. I've edited the answer. Maybe you should get a book on C++ and understand the basics of creating objects before worrying about linked lists.